# Eulerian Graphs and Cycle Decompositions

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, eulerian-path

I have been trying to find the following references, it would be helpful if I am linked to either of the two, both of them would be ideal.

[1] H. Fleischner, Cycle decompositions, 2-coverings, removable cycles and the four-color-disease. Progress in Graph Theory, Academic Press, New York (1984) 233-245.

[2] H. Fleischner, Some blood, sweat, but no tears in Eulerian graph theory. Congres. Numer. 63 (1988) 8-48.

Comment: Wow I'm usually good at finding references but these are just straight up nowhere on the internet. The first one is apparently at my lab's library though so I could send you pictures tomorrow if you really need (and if that's allowed).

Comment: Exactly! Usually I am able to as well. 
But if you could do that tomorrow that would be mighty kind of you.

Comment: I took some pictures, you can send me an email (address is in my profile)